# Why TYPO3 9.5.x Fluid Viewhelper f:security only works in Default.html but not in List.html?

Tags: security, templates, fluid, view-helpers, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 9.5.x this code works in the Layout/Default.html template of my extbase extension. But same code does not work in any other template, in example a List.html template. I dont get **any** output of the viewhelper when I use it there. In TYPO3 8.x, it works in every template, not only in the Default.html. Is there a good reason for that? How can i use f:security inside partials and templates that are not Layout/Default.html?

```
<f:security.ifHasRole role="2">
                <f:then>
                    <p>CHECK RIGHTS role=2</p>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <p>CHECK RIGHTS role=not2</p>
                </f:else>
</f:security.ifHasRole>
```

Same with this code, so it has nothing to do with the f:else:

```
<f:security.ifAuthenticated>
            <p>I AM LOGGED IN, but it does not show up :( </p>
</f:security.ifAuthenticated>
```

Layout/Default.html:

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <f:security.ifHasRole role="2">
        <p>ROLE is 2 in Default.html, this  gets rendered as expected</p>
    </f:security.ifHasRole>
    <div class="container">
        <f:debug title="Debug" maxDepth="12">{_all}</f:debug>
        <f:render section="content" />
    </div><!-- /container -->
</html>
```

Templates/Statistic/List.html

```
<html xmlns:f="https://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
    <f:layout name="Default" />

    This Template is responsible for creating a table of domain objects.

    If you modify this template, do not forget to change the overwrite settings
    in /Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yaml:
    Resources:
    Private:
    Templates:
    List.html: keep

    Otherwise your changes will be overwritten the next time you save the extension in the extension builder

    <f:section name="content">
        <h3>Anruf-Statistiken</h3>
        <f:flashMessages />
        <div style="float:right; clear:both;"><f:link.action action="export" controller="Statistic" pluginName="Run"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Tabelle für Excel speichern (CSV-Export)</button></f:link.action></div>



        <table style="padding: 1em; margin-top:2em; width:100%;" class="tx_srv2" >
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 1em;">ID</th>
                <th style="padding: 1em;">Timestamp</th>
                <th style="padding: 1em;"><f:translate key="tx_srv2_domain_model_statistic.agent" /></th>
            <th style="padding: 1em;"><f:translate key="tx_srv2_domain_model_statistic.status" /></th>
            <th style="padding: 1em;"><f:translate key="tx_srv2_domain_model_statistic.campaigntitle" /></th>
            <th style="padding: 1em;"><f:translate key="tx_srv2_domain_model_statistic.duration" /> (sec.)</th>
            <th style="padding: 1em;"><f:translate key="tx_srv2_domain_model_statistic.comment" /></th>
            </tr>
            <f:widget.paginate objects="{statistics}" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 10, insertBelow:1}" as="paginatedStatistics">
                <f:for each="{paginatedStatistics}" as="statistic">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.uid}</td>
                        <td style="padding: 1em;"><f:format.date format="Y-m-d H:i:s">{statistic.crdate}</f:format.date></td>
                    <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.agent.username}</td>
                    <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.status}</td>
                    <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.campaigntitle}</td>
                    <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.duration}</td>
                    <td style="padding: 1em;">{statistic.comment}</td>
                    </tr>
                </f:for>
            </f:widget.paginate>
        </table> 
        <f:security.ifAuthenticated>
            <f:then>
                This part should be shown if there is a frontend user logged in, but it never shows up.
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                This part should be shown if the current user is not logged in., but it also doesnt show up.
            </f:else>
        </f:security.ifAuthenticated>
    </f:section>
</html>
```

In frontend, no content from the f:security part in List.html gets rendered, but the f:security part from Default.html gets rendered. And the usual output from the List.html, which is the listing of objects, is rendered as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in TYPO3 9.5.x it seems like that the ViewHelper only returns a boolean and does not render the "then" or "else" tags. This works for me:

```html
<f:if condition="{f:security.ifHasRole( role: '9')}">
<f:then>
yes
</f:then>
<f:else>
no
</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage looks perfectly fine.

`f:security` ViewHelpers only work in the frontend. If you are in backend scope you need to use `f:be.security` equivalents. 
If that does not solve the problem, could you please provide the template code where the malfunctioning ViewHelper is used at?

Comment: I Upated my question with the templates that are used.

Comment: Yes, I use the ViewHelpers only in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

had this Problem in 9.5.2 and checking for role was not an option, heres how i worked around it with the help of the vhs extension:

```
<f:security.ifAuthenticated>
    <f:then>
        <v:variable.set name="isLoggedIn" value="true"/>
    </f:then>
</f:security.ifAuthenticated>

<f:if condition="{isLoggedIn}">
    <f:then>### Logged In ###</f:then>
    <f:else>### Not Logged In ###</f:else>
</f:if>
```

The trick here was that the Viewhelper was able to do what is in the `f:then` block, but not what is in the `f:else` block, so i created a variable that is only set in the `f:then` block and later check for this variable.